# How to make a dummy security-domain in JBoss EAP 6.2?

Tags: jboss, jms

We are using the JBoss supplied generic resource adapter to connect to JMS queues on Tibco EMS server. We don't use any authentication to connect to Tibo EMS, that is we connect without username and password. However, the configuration of the resource adapter requires a recovery element (for XA recovery) that specifies some kind of authentication, see [1].

Someone mentioned that we might be able to define a custom security domain that always authenticates or returns empty username and passwords. (Specifying empty username or password directly in the recover element is not allowed)

Does anyone know how to make such a dummy security-domain?

We're running JBoss EAP 6.2.2.

[1] https://access.redhat.com/site/solutions/361463

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This snippet in the standalone.xml did the trick:

```
    <subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:security:1.2">
        <security-domains>
            <security-domain name="no-authentication" cache-type="default">
                <authentication>
                    <login-module code="ConfiguredIdentity" flag="required">
                        <module-option name="username" value=""/>
                        <module-option name="password" value=""/>
                        <module-option name="principal" value=""/>
                    </login-module>
                </authentication>
            </security-domain>
        </security-domains>
    </subsystem>
```